# How to create an Accordion Menu?

Tags: java, android

I want to create Menu like this. Tap on any Item it will open Submenu with Items

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206476/how-to-create-expandable-menu-in-android

Comment: This type of UI interaction is not common in both Android and iOS platforms. If you want to stick with the design guidelines, should ideally handle menus like this using a expandable list view or a drill down into a separate screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists a library which will allow you to do this. (I may be wrong).

But according to me the best possible way to achieve this would be to use two tableViews placed next to each other and updating the the data for the second tableView on didSelectRow of the first tableView. You would have manage a few complexities but it is achievable.

If you only have 2 level of details in your menu, you could also use one tableView, show the 1st level elements in the section header, and create rows on section header click (using a button or tap) for the second level elements.

**Edit:**

My answer mentions some iOS naming conventions. Because it was originally asked for iOS with tag iOS and swift. I decided not change the original answer because the core concept of achieving this should be similar on both platforms.

Anyways, I think you can still do same stuff for android, just use list view where I mentioned tableView

Comment: Expandable Table view I have done but I want exactly Like this. Thanks

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you to place a list view next to your first list and update its values whenever the user clicks on the relevant menu item.

creating your own stuff is always better than using someone else's library.